# SQL Query to display string values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write Stored Procedure to get the following output when I pass the parameter 1,

```
 column_name
 -----------
  option 1
  option 2
  option 3
```

and when I pass the parameter 2 the output should be,

```
  column_name
  -----------
    option 5
    option 6
```

Is it possible to create procedure to get this output without using any tables?

Comment: Based on what logic do you select which rows are displayed?

Comment: Yes, sounds possible! What have you tried?

Comment: In front end if i choose yes the parameter will be passed as 1 if no the parameter is 2 then the corresponding values populated in dropdown box

Comment: i've tried "select 'option 1',option 2',option 3'"

Comment: Why do you wanna hit the Server/DB when this simple task can be handled at front-end itself?

Answer (score 1):

I use `SELECT FROM VALUES` for such tasks. Possible solution for your case:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM (VALUES
         ( 'option 1' )
        ,( 'option 2' )
        ,( 'option 3' )
     ) result (column_name)
WHERE @param = 1

UNION

FROM (VALUES
         ( 'option 5' )
        ,( 'option 6' )
     ) result (column_name)
WHERE @param = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a combination of SELECTs and UNIONs you can produce hand-constructed tables like so:

```
SELECT 'Option 1' as Option
UNION
SELECT 'Option 2' as Option
UNION
SELECT 'Option 3' as Option
```

You can combine this with a control/flow statement to determine which SELECT/UNION combo should be used.  Unfortunately you have MySQL and sql server tags, so I can't make the syntax for the stored proc more specific, but hopefully that should be the bit you're comfortable with!

Answer (score 0):

no need to create any physical table in database for storing these information . you can use temporary table or table variable in store procedure to store these data . you can create store procedure like :

```
create PROCEDURE temp
@id int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @temptable table (column_name varchar(max))

    if @id = 1
    begin
        insert into @temptable values('option 1');
        insert into @temptable values('option 2');
        insert into @temptable values('option 3');
    end

    if @id = 2
    begin
        insert into @temptable values('option 4');
        insert into @temptable values('option 5');
    end

    select * from @temptable            
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ArbitraryOutput (@parm Int)
AS
    CASE 
       WHEN COALESCE(@parm, 1) = 1 THEN 
           SELECT "option 1" AS column_name
              UNION 
           SELECT "option 2" AS column_name
              UNION 
           SELECT "option 3" AS column_name
       WHEN @parm = 2 THEN          
           SELECT "option 4" AS column_name
              UNION 
           SELECT "option 5" AS column_name
              UNION 
           SELECT "option 6" AS column_name
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspTest 
(
   @param INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF @param = 1
       SELECT 'Option 1' column_name 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Option 2'  
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Option 3' 
    ELSE
       SELECT 'Option 5' column_name  
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Option 6'  
 END
```